# .NET dll not appearing in using directive when i'm inside a folder in the solution

Tags: asp.net, dll

I already added my dll in the references but when I try to add it to the using directive, my dll isn't appearing when I'm inside a folder (ex. App_Code/User.cs)
but when I try to add it on the Home.aspx.cs my dll appears on the using directive.

How can I make my dll appear on the using directive in the subfolders within the solution?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "appears on the using directive". Note that using directives specify *namespaces*, not assemblies.

Comment: what i mean is to add DLL to the project, i need to add references by Rightclicking References then Add References>Select the dll>OK
and to use my dll to a class i need to do "using jcgeneral;"
but the namespace of my dll isn't appearing. sorry for the mistake